# Как включить автокомплит (автозавершение команд) в MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

1. Cоздал файл ~/.my.cnf

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

2. Рестартанул демон
3. Автокомплит не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автокомплит (автозавершение слов)

- Включен по умолчанию, что включает завершение **имени БД, таблицы и столбца**
- Для завершения имени введите первую часть и нажмите клавишу Tab. Если имя однозначно, mysql завершает его. В противном случае, вы можете нажать Tab еще раз, чтобы увидеть возможные имена
- **Завершение не происходит, если нет БД по умолчанию** (т.е. **USE mybase;**)

Если автокомплит не включен
mysql --auto-rehash
ИЛИ

Cоздать файл ~/.my.cnf

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

Спасибо за [помощь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592915/how-do-i-enable-autocomplete-in-mariadb) [Реймонду Ниджленду](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548147/raymond-nijland)